# SQL Server: How do you prevent data being modified through an exposed view?

Tags: sql-server, security, view

I have a database: `DB 1`

In a different database `DB 2`, I want to create a bunch of views that reference data in `DB 1`. These views will be relatively complex, with lots of joins, aggregations, sub-queries, etc.

I don't want users of `DB 2` to be able to modify the data in `DB 1`. i.e. I don't want users to be able to be able to execute INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE queries on the view.

This blog post: http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/views/creating-readonly-views

suggests I can use an `INSTEAD` clause. I would prefer to just dissalow certain query clauses on the view itself except for a particular user. Is this possible?

Comment: Perhaps you could just provide access with `GRANT SELECT` against the view.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is handled through the view's and table's security. Grant only `SELECT` permission to the view and the underlying tables.

Without write access, INSERTs, UPDATEs and DELETEs through the view will fail.

If the users have access through a group, and you want the group to still have access but not these specific users, you could use the `DENY` permission since `DENY` has precedence over `GRANT`.

Comment: The underlying tables (in a separate database) need to update permissions as though. Can i grant SELECT permission to just the view?

Comment: @ZachSmith, but who needs those update permissions on the tables? And who needs the access denied?

Comment: I want the tables in `DB 1` to be editable only when accessed as that database (with a user who has permissions on that database). I want views to be select only for every user on `DB 2` (I.e. no UPDATE, INSERT, DELETE, etc). However the view itself needs to be alterable by the same users that cannot update data through that view

Comment: You could try a trigger where it will rollback with transaction if it's initiated from a remote database. I don't have the code for that though.

Comment: (OhEmGee It's the great @TaraKizer).  Related question: Is my SOP of Creating a reporting or application user with 'db_denydatareader' and 'db_denydatawriter' and only giving them CRUD (SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE) as needed on specific objects correct?  It's basically my way of trying to lock down as much as possible.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @MguerraTorres, you could do that, but I just grant the needed permissions and then use deny as necessary.

Comment: Nice, thanks.  What if I don't want them to even know the other objects exist (via the Object Explorer or Information_Schema).  Is deny the only way?

Comment: @MguerraTorres I'm not sure, but I don't think that's possible.

Comment: @TaraKizer I already do it via db_denydatareader and db_denydatawriter.  Whatever user I give those to can't see any objects at all in a Database.  Once I grant them specific SELECT on an object, then they're able to see the object in the Object Browser and Select from it.  Just wanted to see if there were any other methods of doing so.  Thanks for all your contributions!

Comment: @TaraKizer, have you considered cross-database ownership chaining? That would allow you to grant SELECT permissions on the view with no granted table permissions for view users.  The tables will be editable only for users that have direct table permissions.